# Using MICE with Random forests taking into account clustering

Tags: r, random-forest, missing-data, hierarchical-clustering, mice

I am using the `mice` package in R to create multivariate imputed datasets. For this, I am using `mice(data, meth= "rf")`function. I want all the variables to use this method for prediction because there are many non-linear relationships and hypothetical interactions between several of the variables. http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2014/01/12/aje.kwt312.full

My dataset is also a hierarchical dataset with clustering. Is there a way to take this clustering into account when specifying the prediction matrix for the `mice` function? I am aware that if you use other methods like `meth = 2l.pan` or `meth =2l.norm`, you can take clustering into account, but I want to avoid these methods because I think the non-linear relationships trump the homogeneity introduced by the cluster effect.

If there is a way to use the random forest method with MICE and take clustering into account, could you also provide some mock code for specifying the prediction matrix?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the *rf* already is able to take into account the clustering.

Comment: That was my thought, but i'm not so sure since I don't have a huge theoretical underpinning to go on.